# Error No overload matches this call TS2769

Tags: angular, typescript

There is an interface

```
export interface Product {
  type?: string
  id?: string
  title?: string
  date?: Date
}
```

In the service, we call the method

```
  getById(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.fbDbUrl}/products/${id}.json`)
      .pipe( map ( (res: Product) => {
        return {
          ...res,
          id,
          date: new Date(res.date)
        }
      }))
  }
```

IDEA swears at the line

```
date: new Date(res.date)
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 4, '(value: string | number | Date): Date', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'Date | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date'.       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | Date'.   Overload 2 of 4, '(value: string | number): Date', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'Date | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
```

I understand that the compiler swears that res.date may not be defined.
But I can't figure out how to insert a check into this stream

```
if (res && res.date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want `date` to be if `res.date` is undefined.

A possibility might be

```js
    date: res && res.date && new Date(res.date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `date` should be `undefined` in case `res.date` is `undefined`, you should fix like this.

```
  date: res?.date == null ? undefined : new Date(res.date)
```

Comment: So it gives the error "TS2551: Property 'Date' does not exist on type 'Product'. Did you mean 'date'?"

Comment: Yes, I have fiexed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
date: res?.date?.toDate()
```

Comment: So it gives the error "T2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Product'."

Comment: it was a typo. put date instead of data